# Does the state forbid competition with so-called natural monopolies?

Tags: business, regulations

(I don't need information about specific country, so it's OK to post information about laws of country that you know, just remember to include the name of the country in your post).
For example, I heard that the state forbids competition with public utilities. So you can't have two water pipes systems in your house, even if you're willing to pay big money for it. You can't open new water-pipes company, it would be against the law.
Is it correct? I just can't find anything that would either support or disprove such information.
If it's correct, then I would want you to provide me few examples of this.

Comment: So are you asking if in some jurisdiction, the government grants a statutory monopoly for something? Telecommunications in Saudi Arabia is one example, and there are a few zillion other examples.

Comment: Usually these rules are manifested in a general requirement that monopoly service providers of certain kinds get permission from a local government (a requirement contained in a local government ordinance) or a state public utility commission which establishes the requirement by regulation, and then the details are set out in an individually negotiated contract between the governmental entity and the provider. They are usually put up for bid every ten or twenty years. Boulder, Colorado, for example, just dumped theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't open new water-pipes company, it would be against the law. Is it correct?

In the US it depends on state law.

According to [Wisconsin law](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/document/statutes/196.50):

> (a) Except as provided in par. (am), the commission may not grant any person a license, permit or franchise to own, operate, manage or control any plant or equipment for the production, transmission, delivery or furnishing of heat, light, water or power in the municipality, if there is in operation under an indeterminate permit a public utility engaged in similar service in the municipality, unless the person seeking the license, permit or franchise secures from the commission a declaration, after a public hearing of any interested party, that public convenience and necessity require the delivery of service by the applicant.

So it's not technically *prohibited* to have a second utility under Wisconsin law; it's just that you have to show a very good reason.